# How to View local servers on android?

Tags: android, sockets, networking, server

I'm relatively new to the field of android development and am running into a question I cannot find anything about online.  Im wondering what the best way to view a list of local servers would be.

Scenario:
There are 2 "parties" being hosted on my network.  I would like to view the title of these "parties" in a list and choose one to connect to.

I understand that first a connection must be established in order to send and receive data between a host and a client, but I would like for a potential client to be able to receive connection info from a host in order to connect.

Comment: `Scenario: There are 2 "parties" being hosted on my network.`. Party is not a name to be used. I think you would say: "there are two servers running on my local network".And further: "How can a potential client of one of these servers discover which servers are running/available?".

Comment: If there are only two servers running on your local network (on the same pc?)(different ports?)(same protocol?)  then you could just try to connect to them to see if they are in the air. What problem do you have with that? Which connection info are you talking about? What do you mean with 'Title'? What would the user see then?

Comment: What setup do you have that one client should be able to connect to two different servers?

Comment: Hopefully this clarifies:  I want to provide a service where a user can host a party.  There should be able to be multiple parties hosted over the same network.  The potential clients should be able to view a list of local parties and join whichever they want.  The parties should support 1 host and X number of clients.

Comment: What is hosting a party? A party?

Comment: I am using the word party synonymous with "group" or "server" I suppose.

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you want. And you keep talking using your own fantasy words and not the ones that are normally used.

Comment: I would hardly consider that a fantasy word.  I dont think it is unclear at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way would be to make the servers broadcast UDP packets on a particular port and listen to incoming TCP connections on another port. The client would listen to the particular port and update the list of servers. On selection of a server, the client should make a TCP connection with server on a different port.

Sample UDP service listener

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import org.apache.http.util.ExceptionUtils;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


/*
 * Linux command to send UDP:
 * #socat - UDP-DATAGRAM:192.168.1.255:11111,broadcast,sp=11111
 */
public class UDPListenerService extends Service {
static String UDP_BROADCAST = "UDPBroadcast";

//Boolean shouldListenForUDPBroadcast = false;
DatagramSocket socket;

private void listenAndWaitAndThrowIntent(InetAddress broadcastIP, Integer port) throws Exception {
    byte[] recvBuf = new byte[15000];
    if (socket == null || socket.isClosed()) {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(port, broadcastIP);
        socket.setBroadcast(true);
    }
    //socket.setSoTimeout(1000);
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
    Log.e("UDP", "Waiting for UDP broadcast");
    socket.receive(packet);

    String senderIP = packet.getAddress().getHostAddress();
    String message = new String(packet.getData()).trim();

    Log.e("UDP", "Got UDB broadcast from " + senderIP + ", message: " + message);

    broadcastIntent(senderIP, message);
    socket.close();
}

private void broadcastIntent(String senderIP, String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(UDPListenerService.UDP_BROADCAST);
    intent.putExtra("sender", senderIP);
    intent.putExtra("message", message);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

Thread UDPBroadcastThread;

void startListenForUDPBroadcast() {
    UDPBroadcastThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress broadcastIP = InetAddress.getByName("172.16.238.255"); //172.16.238.42 //192.168.1.255
                Integer port = 11111;
                while (shouldRestartSocketListen) {
                    listenAndWaitAndThrowIntent(broadcastIP, port);
                }
                //if (!shouldListenForUDPBroadcast) throw new ThreadDeath();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("UDP", "no longer listening for UDP broadcasts cause of error " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    UDPBroadcastThread.start();
}

private Boolean shouldRestartSocketListen=true;

void stopListen() {
    shouldRestartSocketListen = false;
    socket.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopListen();
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    shouldRestartSocketListen = true;
    startListenForUDPBroadcast();
    Log.i("UDP", "Service started");
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

[Code gist](https://gist.github.com/finnjohnsen/3654994)

Comment: This is extremely helpful.  One thing about the structure I'm confused about however:  who would be the host of this server that is collecting the nearby party information?

Comment: I'm not sure if I have understood your question correctly. Servers are the local servers. Not written as Android Apps. The client will be an android app. The code above will be inside the android app. There should an activity listening to the intents sent by the service.

Comment: Right sorry, server might have been the incorrect word.  From what I understand is that sockets need exactly 1 host and a number of clients.  In this case where the "party" hosts are sending metadata out to potential clients, who is the host?


EDIT: Or do I just use the local IP and hardcode a reserved port for the local party data?

Comment: UDP messages happen over an IP. Every client who is listening over a port on a network will get the message. Read about UDP and broadcasts. Whereas TCP connection happens on a socket, here only two communicating entities are involved. I suggest the local servers run a TCP connection on a different port.

Comment: `possible way would be to make the servers broadcast UDP packets`. What i'm missing in your Answer is that you provide that code too. You could just do it for an Android server.

Comment: `From what I understand is that sockets need exactly 1 host and a number of clients.` ?? You talk in a not usual way. You need a server to begin with. And then there can be clients of that server. One or more. Both server and clients run on a different host/computer/pc/device. But server and client can run on the same device too.